# PHP: How to use %u in crc32 function

Tags: php, authentication, reverse-engineering, crc32

my auth not working like, my code is below.

```
<?php
$login = "super";
printf(crc32($login)); // result -691938802
printf("%u",crc32($login)); //result 3603028494
if(crc32($login) * -1 == -3603028494) {
    echo "user correct";
}else{
    echo "user false";
}
?>
```

i always getting user false, so, i think the problem come from %u , how i can change my $login variable with something like `$login = "%usuper"`
so my auth code working ? is it possible change `$login` value only without change if condition, because i will use it in login form in the future.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why you expect -691938802 * -1 to be a negative number in PHP. Or were you expecting `printf("%u", ...` to convert the result of `crc32($login)` to an unsigned integer every time you call that function in the future?

Comment: @Cairnarvon, exactly i learn to answer quiz , and the simple code looks like my code , so in this case how i can pass to user correct with the above condition given from the quiz.

Answer (score 0):

`crc32()` returns an int, which is a signed 32-bit integer.  The two numbers you are showing are the *same number*, i.e. exactly the same 32 bits, just interpreted differently.  2^32 - 691938802 == 3603028494.  There is no problem.

Comment: if both number is same , then why i always getting user false ? the if condition is as is since i learn answer quiz. so how i can modify "super" string ?
Thanks.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking.  In the code you show, it makes no sense to multiply by -1.  Just compare to -691938802.  It is not clear how what you have written is used in the context of a real program.  Obviously you can determine that `crc32("super")==crc32("super")`.